# When mutual inductance are occurring between two coils, why the two coils have the same mutual inductance?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

I learned that 
$$\epsilon_1 = -M_{12}\frac{di_2}{dt}$$
$$\epsilon_2 = -M_{21}\frac{di_1}{dt}$$

And the book tells us directly that $M_{12} = M_{21}$ without a reason. Is there a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/notes/modules/guide11.pdf

Comment: The above link talks about the reciprocity theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An elegant and elementary derivation is given by Crawford:"Mutual inductance $M_{12}=M_{21}$", American Journal of Physics, vol 60 , February 1962, p186.
The idea is the following: the total stored energy rate, "power" is $$\frac{du}{dt} = L_1i_1\frac{di_1}{dt} + M_{12}i_1\frac{di_2}{dt} + L_2i_2\frac{di_2}{dt} + M_{21}i_2\frac{di_1}{dt}$$
This can be written as the differential 
$${du} = L_1d(i_1^2/2) + M_{12}i_1di_2 + L_2d(i_2^2/2) + M_{21}i_2di_1$$
Now integrate from $i_1(t=0)=i_2(t=0)=0$ to $I_1,I_2$ and get $$U=\frac{1}{2}L_1I_1^2 +M_{12}I_1I_2+\frac{1}{2}L_2I_2^2+(M_{21}-M_{12})\int {i_2di_1}$$.

In general, the integral $\int {i_2di_1}$ can be anything and will depend on the history of the currents, and thus $U$ is not necessarily single valued function of the present currents $I_1,I_2$ unless $M_{21}=M_{12}$! Now you can see that for a simple medium we must have equality of the mutual inductances.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "simple medium"? I thought this result is a generic one, valid for any case

Comment: a simple medium is $\mathbf{B}=\mu \mathbf{H}$ where $\mu$ is a scalar independent of the fields; a ferromagnetic material is not a simple magnetic medium in this sense and the reciprocity does not hold.

Comment: May I know why U not being a single-valued function of I1 and I2 is a problem? (Does this have anything to do with a simple medium? What if it’s not a simple medium?)

Comment: @JY_Decipherer with B-H hysteresis the current value of the flux $\Phi$ (or B) depends on the time history of the excitation $I(t-\tau)$ (or H) for all $t$ and $\tau$ not just on its current value at $t$.

Comment: Why must the energy not depend on the history of the system? It seems right, but I can't formulate a logical argument why it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Sid of course, the energy may depend on the history, an example would be ferromagnetic hysteresis, another example a temperature dependent core with Joule heating from the wires, and then the derivation is not valid. The point is that if the energy *is* independent  of history, for example coils without  core then reciprocity follows.

Comment: That is my question. How do you justify the independence for coils without core?

Comment: @Sid if there is no core, just windings, and $\Phi_1$, the flux in loop $1$, induced by $i_2$ then $M_{12}=\frac{\Phi_1}{i_2}$ is strictly geometry dependent.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by *hyportnex* is an elegant solution that does not even explicitly use the definition of mutual inductance. I also learned this in the textbook but had been wondering about whether one can prove this through brutal force. This is, therefore, a complementary proof that gives a straightforward approach by performing integration using the definition. Sometimes it is worthy to work the non-elegant part out explicitly.

$$M_{12}=M_{2\to 1}=\frac{1}{I_2}\phi_{2\to 1}
=\frac{1}{I_2}\int_{S_2}\mathbf{B}_{2\to 1}\cdot d\mathbf{S}_1$$
$$=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi I_2}\int_{S_2}\oint_{L_1}\frac{I_2d\mathbf{r}_2\times \mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}\cdot d\mathbf{S}_1
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{S_2}\oint_{L_1}\frac{d\mathbf{r}_2\times \mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}\cdot d\mathbf{S}_1 ,$$
where $\mathbf{S_1}$ represents the surface of the coil $\mathbf{L_2}$, subscript $1\to 2$ indicates a quantity generated at the location of the second coil by the current of first coil, for instance $\mathbf{B}_{1\to 2}$ means the magnetic induction at position $\mathbf{r}_2$ generated by an infinitesimal piece of coil $d\mathbf{r}_1$ with current $I_1$. Also, $\mathbf{r}_{12}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2$, $r_{12}=|\mathbf{r}_{12}|$, $\nabla_1\equiv \nabla_{\mathbf{r}_1}$.

We observe that the resultant expression is entirely *geometrical*.
To be specific, it only depends on the geometrical layouts of the two coils but not the currents. One can similarly write down the corresponding expression for $M_{12}$, and try to show that these two expressions are indeed the same by some manipulations, which are the focus of this write-up.

To proceed further, we note the following mathematical relations:
$$\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}=-\nabla\frac{1}{r} ,$$
and in particular, one has
$$\frac{\mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}=-\nabla_1\frac{1}{r_{12}}=+\nabla_2\frac{1}{r_{12}}.$$
This is because for any scalar function $f=f(r_{12})$, we have, in general,
$$\nabla_1 f(r_{12})=-\nabla_2f(r_{12})=-\nabla_2f(r_{21}) ,$$
and therefore
$$\nabla_1\nabla_1 f(r_{12})=\nabla_2\nabla_2f(r_{12})=\nabla_2\nabla_2f(r_{21}) .$$

We further introduce the vectorial part. To start with, we have
$$\mathbf{A}\times(\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{C})=(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{C})\mathbf{B}-(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})\mathbf{C} .$$
we can further introduce the vectorial operator $\nabla$ into the above formula
$$\nabla\times(\mathbf{B}\times \nabla \phi)=(\nabla\cdot \nabla\phi)\mathbf{B}-(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{B})\nabla\phi= -(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{B})\nabla\phi ,$$
where $\phi$ is an arbitrary scalar field that satisfies
$$\nabla\cdot \nabla\phi =0.$$

Now we have all the pieces to continue the calculation, using the Stokes theorem
$$\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{S_2}\oint_{L_1}\frac{d\mathbf{r}_2\times \mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}\cdot d\mathbf{S}_1
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{S_2}\oint_{L_1}\left(d\mathbf{r}_2\times \frac{\mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}\right)\cdot d\mathbf{S}_1$$
$$=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{L_2}\oint_{L_1}\left[\nabla_1\times\left(d\mathbf{r}_2\times \frac{\mathbf{r_{12}}}{r_{12}^3}\right)\right]\cdot d\mathbf{r}_1
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{L_2}\oint_{L_1}\left[\nabla_1\times\left(d\mathbf{r}_2\times (-1)\nabla_1\frac{1}{r_{12}}\right)\right]\cdot d\mathbf{r}_1$$
$$=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{L_2}\oint_{L_1}\left[\nabla_1\cdot d\mathbf{r}_2\nabla_1\frac{1}{r_{12}}\right]\cdot d\mathbf{r}_1
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{L_2}\oint_{L_1}\left[\nabla_1\nabla_1 \left(\frac{1}{r_{12}}\right)\right]: d\mathbf{r}_1d\mathbf{r}_2
=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{L_2}\oint_{L_1}\left[\nabla_2\nabla_2 \left(\frac{1}{r_{21}}\right)\right]: d\mathbf{r}_1d\mathbf{r}_2 .$$

The last step is readily shown identical to the result obtained the other way around, in other words, one finds
$$M_{12}=M_{2\to 1}=M_{1\to 2}=M_{21} .$$