What logic is being used in Bleaney & Bleaney to prove the reciprocity theorem for mutual inductance?
I'm currently reading Bleaney & Bleaney 3rd Ed. On pg 136 they discuss the case of 2 coils. Their logic is as follows:
If a second coil is brought near to a coil carrying a current $I_1$, there will be a magnetic flux $\Phi_2$ through the second coil due to the current in the first coil. This is linearly proportional to $I_1$ so we can write $\Phi_2 = L_{21} I_{1}$ for a constant $L_{21}$. There will also be a flux $\Phi_1$ through the first circuit due to a current $I_2$ in the second circuit, given by $\Phi_1 = L_{12} I_{2}$ for a constant $L_{12}$.
The potential energy of the system can be found from the flux of either coil due to the field of another: $U = -\Phi_1 I_1 = -L_{21} I_2 I_1 = -\Phi_2 I_2 = -L_{12} I_1 I_2$.
Hence $L_{12} = L_{21}$.
However I am struggling to understand the setup. Is there a current $I_1$ and $I_2$ flowing in both coils simultaneously? If so, why is the potential energy not $U = -\Phi_{11} I_1 - \Phi_{21} I_1 -\Phi_{22} I_2 - \Phi_{21} I_2$ where $\Phi_{ij}$ is the flux produced by coil i that threads coil j.
(If there is only a current through one coil at a time, I still dont understand their logic, as why should the potential energy when coil 1 has a current $I_1$ be equal to the potential energy when coil 2 has current $I_2$, given we haven't assumed that the coils are identical)
So I have 2 questions.

In this derivation for $L_{12} = L_{21}$ is there a current through both coils simultaneously?
Why can "The potential energy of the system can be found from the flux of either coil due to the field of another". Why can the flux produced by e.g. coil 1 which threads coil 1 be ignored?


@hyportnex thanks! would still be good to understand where my intuition is wrong in my above working though.

Each loop carries a fixed current kept independently from the other irrespective of their relative positions. In fact, the EM work it takes to keep the currents constant as the loops are moved relative to each other is the magnetic energy stored in the system. To prove $L_{12}=L_{21}$ there is a simple "physical" proof and there is also a straightforward vector calculus based  "analytical" proof, both are here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150068/when-mutual-inductance-are-occurring-between-two-coils-why-the-two-coils-have-t

Have you already read p.147?

@Peltio not yet, but i just had a look: something about stored energy is not equal to potential energy? So I assume I am confused at exactly what $U$ is here and hence am making an error.

Oooh I think I get it: $U$ here is the energy associated with the coils being close together, instead of infinitely far apart (and hence we can ignore their self inductances)?

@psychgiraffe uhm... I think it's more what hyportnex said. Let's see if I can give you an alternate pov: keep your coils close, make a current I1 in the first coil and leave the second open. The flux from the first coil will be intercepted by the second one. Now, if you want to pass a current in the second coil to generate a given flux you need to first cancel the flux that was there without current and then build your own flux. So, in one computation this extra cancellation work is not included, while in the other it is.

@Peltio I still dont understand why there aren't two terms in the potential energy: in building the flux in the 2nd coil, wouldnt you also be affecting the flux through the 1st?

If you wish to understand how the energy gets built to which @Peltio alluded to, please, read Jackson: Classical Electrodynamics, Section 5.16 and then if something is still not clear then ask in a separate new question specifically what steps need clarification. Mutual inductance is in the next Section 5.17
